# JavaScript: How do I run a function being passed as a paremeter inside an array?

Tags: javascript

I am running through some JavaScript exercises. One of them uses an array as a parameter.

The function to solve the exercise should go through the input array, test for the type of what is coming in, and add the item to a new array to be returned.
The input array can contain a variety of types including a function.
If an item is a function, you are required to call it/run instead of adding it to a new array. The result should be added to the new array to be returned.

I can test for a function in the input array using "typeof". No problem.
How do I call/run that function?

So, here is an example of an input array that has a function as an item:

```
flattenArray([1, '2', 3, 4, function () { return 'five'; }]);
```

The resulting array being returned should be:

```
[1, '2', 3, 4, 'five']
```

Here is the section of my code where I am testing for an object in the loop that goes through the input array (named "array").

```
var arrReturn = [];

for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
// Test for a function.
// Run/call the function.
    if(typeof array[i] === "function"){
        var functionResult = array[i];  // This is not correct. What should go here? 
        arrReturn.push(functionResult);
    }
}
```

I would gladly take a link to a page in MDN or somewhere else as an answer as I want to learn how to do this.

Comment: `array[i]()` --- as soon as it's a function you need to invoke it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to call the function:

```
// Add () to call, just like you would any other function. 
var functionResult = array[i]();
```

It may make more sense if you break it down into two steps:

```
var func = array[i];
var result = func(); // Calling
```

Comment: The two versions do not do the same thing, exactly. In the first example, the function has access to `array` via `this`, while it doesn't in the second example. If these other functions aren't trusted, the code in the first example can cause a security vulnerability by exposing an internal object to a third party.

Comment: @cdhowie I'll remove that footer to prevent confusion.

Comment: It would probably be better to explain that they don't do the same thing. I've seen real world security issues caused by not realizing that you're passing an object via `this`.

Comment: @cdhowie I'm going to go out on a limb and say that if their asking a question like this, security isn't their primary concern at this point. It's also nearly 10pm. I'm not sure I could write anything coherent explaining it. You're welcome to write a supplemental answer though. You likely have more knowledge on the subject than I do. I honestly haven't written JS for a couple years.

Comment: cdhowie: You are correct. It is just an exercise. No security concerns. I did break it down into two steps.

Answer (score 2):

Execute the function by checking the `typeof` property inside `map()`. Try the following:

```js
var arr = [1, '2', 3, 4, function () { return 'five'; }];

var arrReturn = [];

arrReturn = arr.map(function(item){
  if(typeof item === 'function'){
    item = item();
  }
  return item;
});

console.log(arrReturn);
```